# How do i get my sidebar to have scroll functionality

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a fixed sidebar however the scroll functionality does not work. Can anyone provide feedback on what I am doing wrong?

Also how do I get the border under each link to extend to the end of the page on the left side.

Also, I don't want to use any javascript if possible. Trying to do this through html/css.

```css
body{
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;

}

.sidebar-brand{
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  border-right: 3px solid gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav-link{
  color: gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid gray;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.sidebar{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


.nav-item{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.shadeofgray{
background-color: #f7f7f7;
display:flex;
font-style: italic;
font-size: .9rem;
}

.declaringVariables{
  line-height: 1.6;
}

p{
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="techdocu.css">

    <title>Technical Document Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar sticky-top">
          <ul class="navbar-nav scrollBar">
            <li class="sidebar-brand pt-3">
              <a class ="sidebar-title">JS Documentation </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">What you should already know</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">JavaScript and Java</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hello World</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Variables</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Declaring Variables</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Variable Scope</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gobal Variables</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Constants</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Data Types</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">if...else statement</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">while statement</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Function Declaration</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reference</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reference</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reference</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reference</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reference</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reference</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reference</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div id ="content">
          <h2 class="header"> Introduction </h2>
<p> JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language. It is a small and lightweight language. Inside a host environment (for example, a web browser), JavaScript can be connected to the objects of its environment to provide programmatic control over them.
</p>
<p>JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array, Date, and Math, and a core set of language elements such as operators, control structures, and statements. Core JavaScript can be extended for a variety of purposes by supplementing it with additional objects; for example:
</p>
<ul>
    <li class="indentRight">
      Client-side JavaScript extends the core language by supplying objects to control a browser and its Document Object Model (DOM). For example, client-side extensions allow an application to place elements on an HTML form and respond to user events such as mouse clicks, form input, and page navigation.
      </li>
    <li class="indentRight">
      Server-side JavaScript extends the core language by supplying objects relevant to running JavaScript on a server. For example, server-side extensions allow an application to communicate with a database, provide continuity of information from one invocation to another of the application, or perform file manipulations on a server.
    </li>
</ul>

<h2 class="header"> What you should already know </h2>
<p> This guide assumes you have the following basic background:</P>
  <ul>
    <li class="indentRight">
      A general understanding of the Internet and the World Wide Web (WWW).
    </li>
    <li class="indentRight">
      Good working knowledge of HyperText Markup Language (HTML).
    </li>
    <li class="indentRight">
      Some programming experience. If you are new to programming, try one of the tutorials linked on the main page about JavaScript.
      </li>
    </ul>

  <h2 class="header"> JavaScript and Java </h2>
  <p> JavaScript and Java are similar in some ways but fundamentally different in some others. The JavaScript language resembles Java but does not have Java's static typing and strong type checking. JavaScript follows most Java expression syntax, naming conventions and basic control-flow constructs which was the reason why it was renamed from LiveScript to JavaScript.
</P>
<p> In contrast to Java's compile-time system of classes built by declarations, JavaScript supports a runtime system based on a small number of data types representing numeric, Boolean, and string values. JavaScript has a prototype-based object model instead of the more common class-based object model. The prototype-based model provides dynamic inheritance; that is, what is inherited can vary for individual objects. JavaScript also supports functions without any special declarative requirements. Functions can be properties of objects, executing as loosely typed methods.</p>

<p> JavaScript is a very free-form language compared to Java. You do not have to declare all variables, classes, and methods. You do not have to be concerned with whether methods are public, private, or protected, and you do not have to implement interfaces. Variables, parameters, and function return types are not explicitly typed.
</p>

  <h2 class="header"> Hello world </h2>
<p>To get started with writing JavaScript, open the Scratchpad and write your first "Hello world" JavaScript code:<br></br>
<span class="shadeofgray">function greetMe(yourName) { alert("Hello " + yourName); }</span>
<span class="shadeofgray"> greetMe("World");</span>
<p>Select the code in the pad and hit Ctrl+R to watch it unfold in your browser!</p>

<h2 class="header"> Variables </h2>
<p>You use variables as symbolic names for values in your application. The names of variables, called identifiers, conform to certain rules. </p>
<p> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase). </p>
<p>You can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers. Some examples of legal names are Number_hits, temp99, and _name.</p>

<h2 class="header"> Declaring variables </h2>
<p>You can declare a variable in three ways:
    With the keyword var. For example,
    <code> var x = 42. </code>
    This syntax can be used to declare both local and global variables. </p>

  <p>By simply assigning it a value. For example,
    <span class="shadeofgray"> x = 42. </span>
    This always declares a global variable. It generates a strict JavaScript warning. You shouldn't use this variant.</p>

  <p>With the keyword let. For example,
    <span class="shadeofgray"> let y = 13.</span>
    This syntax can be used to declare a block scope local variable. See Variable scope below.</p>

    <h2 class="header">Variable scope </h2>
    <p>When you declare a variable outside of any function, it is called a global variable, because it is available to any other code in the current document. When you declare a variable within a function, it is called a local variable, because it is available only within that function.</p>
    <p>JavaScript before ECMAScript 2015 does not have block statement scope; rather, a variable declared within a block is local to the function (or global scope) that the block resides within. For example the following code will log 5, because the scope of x is the function (or global context) within which x is declared, not the block, which in this case is an if statement.</p>
    <span class="shadeofgray"> if (true) { var x = 5; } console.log(x); // 5 </span>
    <p>This behavior changes, when using the let declaration introduced in ECMAScript 2015.</p>
    <span class="shadeofgray">  if (true) { let y = 5; } console.log(y); // ReferenceError: y is not <br>defined</br> </span>

      <h2 class="header">Global variables</h2>
      <p>Global variables are in fact properties of the global object. In web pages the global object is window, so you can set and access global variables using the window.variable syntax.</p>
      <p>Consequently, you can access global variables declared in one window or frame from another window or frame by specifying the window or frame name. For example, if a variable called phoneNumber is declared in a document, you can refer to this variable from an iframe as parent.phoneNumber.</p>

      <h2 class="header">Constants </h2>
      <p> You can create a read-only, named constant with the const keyword. The syntax of a constant identifier is the same as for a variable identifier: it must start with a letter, underscore or dollar sign and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters.</p>
    <span class="shadeofgray">const PI = 3.14; </span>
  <p>  A constant cannot change value through assignment or be re-declared while the script is running. It has to be initialized to a value.

    The scope rules for constants are the same as those for let block scope variables. If the const keyword is omitted, the identifier is assumed to represent a variable.

    You cannot declare a constant with the same name as a function or variable in the same scope. For example: </p>

    <span class="shadeofgray">  // THIS WILL CAUSE AN ERROR function f() {}; const f = 5; // THIS WILL <br>
  </br>  CAUSE AN ERROR ALSO function f() { const g = 5; var g; //statements <br>
    }</br></span>
    However, object attributes are not protected, so the following statement is executed without problems.
      <span class="shadeofgray"> const MY_OBJECT = {"key": "value"}; MY_OBJECT.key = "otherValue"; </span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set height `100vh`

```
.sticky-top {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Awais, Thanks so much for your answer. I'm just trying to understand this on a deeper level so I just dont copy what you write. Can you explain why we need to use the z-index and height to accomplish this? Can I not use .sidebar{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

Comment: Dear `z-index` property specifies the stack order of an element that how placed. setting it to high value mean `above all` and second `Sticky` positioning is a hybrid of `relative` and `fixed` positioning,The element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned.

Comment: And third `overflow` property specifies what should happen if content overflows an element's box and obviously it only works for `block` elements with a specified `height`. I am not a good teacher but hope that will help you if not do let me i know ill share some easy understandable links for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**You should use a minimum height for the class .sidebar | scroll will be start when content overflow that height**

> Such as

```
.sidebar{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height : 100%; or
  height : 100vh; or
  height : 450px;
}
```